After installing MediaPipeTasksVision with CocoaPods, I can no longer preview in SwiftUI
I am using SwiftUI to configure my screens.
I want to use Google's MediaPipeTasksVision to run HandTracker, so I installed it with CocoaPods. Then the SwiftUI preview started crashing, although I didn't import any libraries. By the way the arm64 simulator was ran the app on Xcode.
Is there any solution to this problem?
Podfile
platform :ios, '16.0'

target 'Test' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'MediaPipeTasksVision'
end


ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Crash logs
{"app_name":"Test","timestamp":"2024-06-04 09:23:21.00 +0900","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"319d20f8-7e7b-390b-a8eb-aaccc52b0e43","build_version":"1","platform":7,"bundleID":"com.example.Test","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 14.0 (23A344)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Test","incident_id":"1861E09A-5B5C-4EA2-8DB5-E660CCD3F447"}
{
  "uptime" : 400000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro18,3",
  "coalitionID" : 65264,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 14.0",
    "build" : "23A344",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2024-06-04 09:23:19.6284 +0900",
  "codeSigningMonitor" : 1,
  "incident" : "1861E09A-5B5C-4EA2-8DB5-E660CCD3F447",
  "pid" : 11686,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2024-06-04 09:23:19.2334 +0900",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 9721471402160,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 9721480357195,
  "procName" : "Test",
  "procPath" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/UserData\/Previews\/Simulator Devices\/ED02E787-5404-40CB-B97C-87F37D9DAF2F\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/5A9B773F-A948-4D5E-8BB1-F4FC6105D7CC\/Test.app\/Test",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0","CFBundleVersion":"1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.example.Test"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"6B44E0E3-845F-5FB5-89E2-0CA33C044988","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd_sim",
  "parentPid" : 98534,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.ED02E787-5404-40CB-B97C-87F37D9DAF2F",
  "crashReporterKey" : "85482DAC-292C-58A0-112D-EDA589D6C0A7",
  "responsiblePid" : 2502,
  "responsibleProc" : "SimulatorTrampoline",
  "codeSigningID" : "com.example.Test",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570425861,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 10,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 4294967295,
  "instructionByteStream" : {"beforePC":"4wAAVP17v6n9AwCR2OL\/l78DAJH9e8GowANf1sADX9YQKYDSARAA1A==","atPC":"4wAAVP17v6n9AwCRzuL\/l78DAJH9e8GowANf1sADX9ZwCoDSARAA1A=="},
  "wakeTime" : 29,
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "3EF5E7F1-EDB9-46AF-85DA-1543E1CB5DA2",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":6,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Abort trap: 6","byProc":"Test","byPid":11686},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":136,"task_for_pid":23},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":6936481,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":10},{"value":4775065441,"symbolLocation":1041,"symbol":"google::IdentifierIsAnonymousNamespace(google::State*, int)::anon_prefix"},{"value":4419600960,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":8184468163272084700},{"value":257},{"value":4294967293},{"value":1099511627776},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":328},{"value":4462878208},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":4419600960,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":259},{"value":4419601184,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":0},{"value":6095594256},{"value":4742421752},{"value":4742416200},{"value":1},{"value":8368170752,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"type metadata for Logger"}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4418384336},"cpsr":{"value":1073745920},"fp":{"value":6095593872},"sp":{"value":6095593840},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4417063500,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":4754846568}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":35404,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":29136,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":256,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":472512,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":6582840,"symbol":"absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessage::FailWithoutStackTrace()","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":6584136,"symbol":"absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessage::Die()","symbolLocation":36,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":6583472,"symbol":"absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessage::SendToLog()","symbolLocation":128,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":6581748,"symbol":"absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessage::Flush()","symbolLocation":304,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":6584552,"symbol":"absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":6584592,"symbol":"absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()","symbolLocation":12,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":54012,"symbol":"mediapipe::FunctionRegistry<std::__1::unique_ptr<mediapipe::Subgraph, std::__1::default_delete<mediapipe::Subgraph>>>::Register(std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>, std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<mediapipe::Subgraph, std::__1::default_delete<mediapipe::Subgraph>> ()>)","symbolLocation":1216,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":52440,"symbol":"mediapipe::GlobalFactoryRegistry<std::__1::unique_ptr<mediapipe::Subgraph, std::__1::default_delete<mediapipe::Subgraph>>>::Register(std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>, std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<mediapipe::Subgraph, std::__1::default_delete<mediapipe::Subgraph>> ()>)","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":162868,"symbol":"_GLOBAL__sub_I_text_preprocessing_graph.cc","symbolLocation":100,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":82088,"symbol":"invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const::$_0::operator()() const","symbolLocation":152,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":228524,"symbol":"invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const","symbolLocation":332,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":194460,"symbol":"invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const","symbolLocation":488,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":189552,"symbol":"dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":190332,"symbol":"dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":227288,"symbol":"dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const","symbolLocation":376,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":69736,"symbol":"dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const","symbolLocation":384,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":91776,"symbol":"dyld4::JustInTimeLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":70556,"symbol":"dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const","symbolLocation":216,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":82208,"symbol":"dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const::$_1::operator()() const","symbolLocation":92,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":70896,"symbol":"dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const","symbolLocation":264,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":146328,"symbol":"dyld4::APIs::dlopen_from(char const*, int, void*)","symbolLocation":1256,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":75492,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":76848,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":201236,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":198980,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":161305,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":155437,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":161253,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":254157,"symbol":"completeTaskWithClosure(swift::AsyncContext*, swift::SwiftError*)","symbolLocation":1,"imageIndex":10}]},{"id":6936514,"frames":[{"imageOffset":9948,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6096171008},{"value":5635},{"value":6095634432},{"value":0},{"value":409602},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6096171008},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4418365148},"far":{"value":4337893376}}},{"id":6936515,"frames":[{"imageOffset":9948,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6096744448},{"value":4099},{"value":6096207872},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6096744448},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4418365148},"far":{"value":4731158528}}},{"id":6936516,"frames":[{"imageOffset":9948,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6097317888},{"value":8451},{"value":6096781312},{"value":0},{"value":409603},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6097317888},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4418365148},"far":{"value":8298568944}}},{"id":6936529,"frames":[{"imageOffset":9948,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6097891328},{"value":9731},{"value":6097354752},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6097891328},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4418365148},"far":{"value":8469233052}}},{"id":6936530,"frames":[{"imageOffset":9948,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6098464768},{"value":15363},{"value":6097928192},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6098464768},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4418365148},"far":{"value":8130891508}}},{"id":6936531,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","threadState":{"x":[{"value":268451845},{"value":21592279046},{"value":8589934592},{"value":60486024429568},{"value":2162692},{"value":60486024429568},{"value":2},{"value":4294967295},{"value":18446744073709550527},{"value":14083},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":14083},{"value":3072},{"value":2043},{"value":2250473488},{"value":18446744073709551569},{"value":2252570619},{"value":0},{"value":4294967295},{"value":2},{"value":60486024429568},{"value":2162692},{"value":60486024429568},{"value":6099033464},{"value":8589934592},{"value":21592279046},{"value":21592279046},{"value":4412409862}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4417101220},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":6099033312},"sp":{"value":6099033232},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4417031184},"far":{"value":6472560424}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":3088,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":73124,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":36404,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":532,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":3976,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":579204,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":556388,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1148,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":554196,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":572,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":6419468,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":208,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":6420016,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":13206520,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":404,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":6577252,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":720,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":29888,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9968,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":5}]},{"id":6936537,"frames":[{"imageOffset":9948,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6099611648},{"value":19723},{"value":6099075072},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6099611648},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4418365148},"far":{"value":4794548224}}},{"id":6936539,"frames":[{"imageOffset":9948,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6100185088},{"value":0},{"value":6099648512},{"value":0},{"value":278532},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6100185088},"esr":{"value":0,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4418365148},"far":{"value":0}}}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4418945024,
    "size" : 606208,
    "uuid" : "ffd8ab66-c9ab-31df-ab80-3a3dff367ddd",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4742414336,
    "size" : 33488896,
    "uuid" : "d08626e8-dbf1-34f1-8d11-7cff1e42e58e",
    "path" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/Test-blkfoquyskkbswezlqcvqdjuutsj\/Build\/Intermediates.noindex\/Previews\/iphonesimulator\/Test\/Intermediates.noindex\/Test.build\/Debug-iphonesimulator\/Test.build\/Objects-normal\/arm64\/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib",
    "name" : "ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4421697536,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "c6ef2cc0-8ca9-3a69-a525-91bec719ddfc",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/libobjc-trampolines.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc-trampolines.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4418224128,
    "size" : 32768,
    "uuid" : "af2db34b-2633-3ceb-b19c-e000edea762d",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_platform.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_platform.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4417028096,
    "size" : 229376,
    "uuid" : "642a38ac-927b-39b2-9654-365bc3f3c14e",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4418355200,
    "size" : 65536,
    "uuid" : "ca3c77b3-7c7b-312e-a130-32fdc563d382",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4371267584,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.example.Test",
    "size" : 32964608,
    "uuid" : "319d20f8-7e7b-390b-a8eb-aaccc52b0e43",
    "path" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/UserData\/Previews\/Simulator Devices\/ED02E787-5404-40CB-B97C-87F37D9DAF2F\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/5A9B773F-A948-4D5E-8BB1-F4FC6105D7CC\/Test.app\/Test",
    "name" : "Test",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4417650688,
    "size" : 311296,
    "uuid" : "f1d509a4-edf1-3668-b217-c6a2bd1fbef4",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/dyld_sim",
    "name" : "dyld_sim"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6443442176,
    "size" : 507904,
    "uuid" : "ce9466d4-2e24-3c03-a488-d86a828ecffe",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8468733952,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "15.3",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.dt.PreviewsInjection",
    "size" : 442368,
    "uuid" : "e2d22720-7ef9-3f14-926e-61b66f3644e9",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/PreviewsInjection.framework\/PreviewsInjection",
    "name" : "PreviewsInjection",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "21.40.1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8766603264,
    "size" : 339956,
    "uuid" : "5cb10e98-4d78-327e-aa62-6cc99130275a",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/libswift_Concurrency.dylib",
    "name" : "libswift_Concurrency.dylib"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6446125056,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.CoreFoundation",
    "size" : 3883008,
    "uuid" : "6c40f9e5-bffa-3413-9e1c-a4f724ad56ba",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "2503.1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6450528256,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.Foundation",
    "size" : 11210752,
    "uuid" : "3a54db51-8b3a-308d-9f9e-51474c4a8520",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "2503.1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6517813248,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.UIKitCore",
    "size" : 26902528,
    "uuid" : "8d3f22bc-9dec-3601-b822-2b88624be742",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "7511.1.104"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 6442450944,
  "size" : 3294642176,
  "uuid" : "cb17e5ab-08b9-33f7-8801-338a5413afd7"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.4G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.4G(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=750.0M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=750.0M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nAttributeGraph Data               1024K        1 \nColorSync                           32K        2 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           734.4M       44 \nMALLOC guard page                  288K       18 \nSTACK GUARD                       56.1M        9 \nStack                             12.2M        9 \nVM_ALLOCATE                         32K        1 \n__DATA                            17.0M      493 \n__DATA_CONST                      51.9M      510 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       107K       11 \n__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       822.5M        9 \n__LLVM_COV                          32K        2 \n__OBJC_RO                         72.6M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         2515K        1 \n__TEXT                           602.8M      519 \ndyld private memory               1088K        8 \nmapped file                       31.5M        6 \nshared memory                       16K        1 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              2.4G     1649 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "c6d9816f78d57cdcc313b627e3475c37332266d0",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "6297d96be2c9387df974efa4",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000025
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "632e3df958740028737bffc0",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_NL_OVERRIDES" : "65e7a8ec68da4f6d14fe7a05"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000670
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "1ea7cbb4-b1d5-4dea-8c8d-f32724120f8a",
      "experimentId" : "661821ee2ea8460fbd2d47e1",
      "deploymentId" : 400000001
    }
  ]
}
}


You might want to look in the crash logs of previews for clues what's causing the crashes.

Thank you for your comment. I looked at the crash log but could not find the cause. I have added the log.
